# Stacking Icons in Icomoon like fa-stack in Font Awesome

Tags: icons, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, font-awesome-4

How do you stack icons in Iconmoon like the ones in Font Awesome's fa-stack. If not not possible in Icomoon how in CSS? Thanks for the help!  For example if you have two icons a plus sign and a box how do put the plus sign icon on top of the box icon.